# Is in the following sentence "the possessive noun" removed?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

I have just come across the following sentence. I wonder if in the part "a number were", "300 sound movies" is removed? if not why does "were" come after "a number" not "was"?

> In 1929 the United States motion picture industry released more than 300 sound films—a rough figure, since **a number were** silent films with music tracks, or films prepared in dual versions, to take account of the many cinemas not yet wired for sound.

Second, if my assumption is correct, the possessive noun is removed from the above sentence, I have the other question:

> I, myself, usually use "them" in a situation like this, and so the number of pronouns in my text increases. now, can I use the above method to remove extra pronouns, if so when?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The sentence says that a certain number of those films were _not_ actually sound films (with dialogue), but silent films with music tracks.

Comment: I have edited my post, I hope it is clear now.

Comment: My comment still stands. What has been omitted is 'of those films' (the 300 previously mentioned). You could say 'of them' instead. Why are you worried about the number of pronouns?

Comment: To be honest, recently some e-raters are invented to evaluate one's writings. These programs have different criteria to measure, one of them is the number of pronouns. I do not know this considers an advantage or not, but we are inevitable to take such English exams.